# How to open Chrome in the current windows

Tags: google-chrome, windows-11, logitech-mouse

I have used the Logitech options + app to set a custom gesture for my mouse one of the gestures is to open Chrome. I have set it to open the Chrome app but when I do the gesture it opens Chrome in a new window even if there is another one open is there a way to stop this (I think I can also set it to run command prompt if I need to?)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Install [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)
- Create an AutoHotKey Script

Right-click on an empty area of your desktop, then go to New > AutoHotKey Script.

- Copy/Paste this Script into your .ahk file:

`

```
F12::
IfWinExist, ahk_exe chrome.exe
{
    WinActivate
    Send, ^t
}
return
```

This script sets the F12 key to select Google Chrome as the active window and then sends the Ctrl+T command to open a new tab.

- Convert Script to Executable

Find AutoHotKey in your list of applications and select "Convert .ahk to .exe." This will create an executable file from your script.

- Add to Startup Programs

Put that exe file in your user startup folder. The path is: `C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`. This makes sure the script runs each time your user logs in.

- Run the EXE

Double-click the exe file to manually run it. You'll notice a green 'H' icon in your task tray confirming that the script is running. You only need to do this if the script is not running yet. Copying it to your startup folder ensures it will run automatically each time you log in.

- Bind your logitech gesture

Finally, within Logitech Options, bind your desired mouse key or gesture to trigger the F12 key, or whatever key you may have changed the autohotkey script to use instead. This will activate Chrome and open a new tab whenever you run that logitech gesture on your mouse.

If you want the script to open a brand new chrome window (should one not exist yet), and then open new tabs thereafter, then use the following code instead:

```
F12::
IfWinExist, ahk_exe chrome.exe
{
    WinActivate
    Sleep, 100
    Send, ^t
}
else
{
    Run, chrome.exe
}
return
```

Comment: When I compile it to an exe and open it, it tells me that "An older instance of this script is already running. Replace it with this instance? Notes: To avoid this message, see #SingleInstance in the help file. I have tried yes and no and none of them work

Comment: I just tested both .ahk and .exe version and they both work when pressing F12 on the keyboard. Can you confirm what happens when you press F12 on the keyboard when the script has been activated? Keep in mind if you have a laptop, you may need to hold down the "fn" (function key) whilst pressing F12 for it to work. If we can confirm F12 works on the keyboard then it shouldn't be too much trouble mapping that to your mouse logic.

Comment: Thanks its working now

Comment: Great! Glad I was able to help!